# Как склоняются "третьи лица"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование

Предложение такое: "Этот документ можно оформить в электронном виде, минуя третьих лиц". Я написала, а потом зависла: а как, собственно, правильно - "третьих лиц" или "третьи лица"?
Спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: минуя третьих лиц. Для формы мн.числа выражена категория одушевленности, поэтому  форма В.п. совпадает с формой Р.п.

Для сравнения: минуя третье лицо. Для существительных среднего рода категория одушевленности/неодушевленности не выражается, форма В.п. совпадает с И.п.

Comment: Не то, чтобы сомневаюсь, просто навело на рассуждения. Пример: " Я иду сквозь толпу, минуя  угрюмые лица..." - так будет неверно? И: "Я иду сквозь толпу мимо угрюмых лиц".